# Reset Cache using bash

Tags: bash, automation, chromium, sh

I'm trying to automate a `.sh` file to run every time before Chrome opens, here's what I want to do.

```
   rm -rf /home/pi/.config/chromium
   tar -cvf reseterfiles.tgz /home/pi/.config/
```

The zipped contains the settings I want to overwrite every time Chromium opens up. Will this code work effectively? Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good but there are syntax errors in the `tar` command, and to avoid any risk of overwriting files in `.config/` but out of `.config/chromium/`, I'd rather operate in the latter directly:

```
rm -rf /home/pi/.config/chromium/*
tar -xzf reseterfiles.tgz -C /home/pi/.config/chromium
```

---

Sidenote: always test potentially destructive scripts! Here you may want to create a folder `/tmp/chromium`, `touch` some files inside and do your tests.